# Interrupt context bottom half (Softirq or tasklets)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt-handling

Softirqs /tasklets are said to be executed in interrupt context I have below question with respect to interrupt context bottoms half.

Q1) What happen if we try to put sleep in tasklet (interrupt context Bottom half) ( consider that tasklet is scheduled by interrupt handler).

[My understanding]
As I know while coming out of interrupt handler when tasklet_schedule is called it will get get tasklet_vec structure pointer and if currently no other interrupt / high priority softirq in progress it will schedule ksoftirqd which will run handler (tasklet handler) and if a tall that tasklet handler uses sleep in that case ksoftirqd will move to wait_queue and unless and until another tasklet_schdule is called my interrupted tasklet hander will be continue on that point onwards.

We say "Interrupt context code must not sleep" ( What are consequence if I use sleep in interrupt handler, considering I have not used spint lock OR I have not disabled timer interrupt )

(Please correct me if my understanding is wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Sleep works only in process context not in interrupt context. In interrupt context, "current" is not a valid task so we can put it in sleep and wake it up later. Use threads if u wanna sleep

Comment: I am not saying sleep I am referring to any Linux call which is allowed to sleep ( Like semaphore, mutex ) what happens in that case.

Comment: Sleep means not just "sleep" call but any api which sleeps. You can schedule only "scheduler entities" like process and thread. Interrupt does not run in process( or thread - lwp) context.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to sleep in tasklet, there would be a kernel bug indicating context switching in atomic context.
In bottom half, it is interrupt context, and is process context in ksoftirqd.
Regardless of processing tasklet in bottom half or ksoftirqd, `thread_info->preempt_count` is not zero, which meaning atomic context.